# Latex3: How to test if macro is empty?

Tags: macros, conditionals, latex3

How to test if a macro is empty? As you can see in MWE, the `creator1email` is empty (or `\relax` ?), but my test via `\cs_if_exist` get an `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \int_new:N \l_creator_int
    \NewDocumentCommand\creator{ O{} m}
    {
        \int_incr:N \l_creator_int
        \cs_new_protected:cpn {creator\int_use:N\l_creator_int}{#2}
        \cs_new_protected:cpn {creator\int_use:N\l_creator_int email}{#1}
    }
    
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\creator[]{Me}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_if_exist:cTF {creator1email}  {1} {0}

     \use:c {creator1email}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Semantically, you should use `\tl_set:cn { l__<module>_creator \int_use:N \l_creator_int _tl } {#2}`, then you can check whether it's empty with `\tl_if_empty:cTF { l__<module>_creator <num> _tl} { <true> } { <false> }`.

Comment: @Skillmon My creator1emal  is empty or \relax?

Comment: If you set it to an empty value, it's empty.

Comment: @Skillmon But my empty square bracket in \creator set creator1emal to empty. Or not?

Comment: Yes, it did, just like the default would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that `expl3` offers you different data types and also provides tests for those data types. One of these is a token list, which is the correct variable type to store contents which you might want to print out.

The following changes your code to follow `expl3` naming conventions and uses token list variables to store the email addresses. As a result you can use `\tl_if_empty:cTF` to check whether the email is indeed empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sergiokapone_new_creator:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int
    \tl_new:c
      { l__sergiokapone_creator \int_use:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int _tl }
    \tl_new:c
      { l__sergiokapone_email \int_use:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int _tl }
    \tl_set:cn
      { l__sergiokapone_creator \int_use:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int _tl }
      {#2}
    \tl_set:cn
      { l__sergiokapone_email \int_use:N \l_sergiokapone_creator_int _tl }
      {#1}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \creator { O{} m }
  { \sergiokapone_new_creator:nn {#1} {#2} }

\NewDocumentCommand\usemail { m }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:cTF { l__sergiokapone_email #1 _tl }
      { \emph{empty} }
      { \tl_use:c { l__sergiokapone_email #1 _tl } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\creator[]{Me}
\creator{You}
\creator[mail@internet.com]{Him}

\usemail{1}
\usemail{2}
\usemail{3}

\end{document}
```